# Redirect to Page after Facebook Sign Up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth, facebook-oauth

I'm trying to Redirect a user after successful Facebook SIGN UP (not sign in).

I want to redirect to `/getstarted/welcome` after a user Registers **for the first time**.

My omniauth callback is :

```
def facebook
        # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
        @user ||=
            User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

        if @user.persisted?
            # This will throw if @user is not activated
            sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication
            if is_navigational_format?
                set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: "Facebook")
            end
        else
            session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
            redirect_to new_user_registration_url
        end
    end
```

For devise i use

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(source)
  '/getstarted/welcome'
end
```

My User Model:

## Facebook Settings

```
  def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource = nil)
    user = User.where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first
    if user.present?
        user
    else
        user = User.create(first_name:auth.extra.raw_info.first_name,
                                             last_name:auth.extra.raw_info.last_name,
                                             facebook_link:auth.extra.raw_info.link,
                                             user_name:auth.extra.raw_info.name,
                                             provider:auth.provider,
                                             uid:auth.uid,
                                             email:auth.info.email,
                                             password:Devise.friendly_token[0,20])
    end
end
```

Can someone help me set this up ?

Comment: so, does this work? if not any errors?

Comment: Hey Billy, i tried a lot of variations but nothings seems to work. The code above is my simple callbacks controller. I need someone help me implement the redirect after the FIRST sign up :)

Comment: You'd better to provide errors or it's hard to know what happened.

Comment: Well there are no Errors, if i don't write in the correct way :/ The problem is i dont know where to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by adding to my User model

```
attr_accessor `just_signed_up`
```

and setting it in `User.find_for_facebook_oauth` in this part of the block where I create a new user (`first_or_create` block).

EDIT: more explanation

So in Ruby (not Rails) there is a class method/macro called `attr_accessor` (actually theres also `attr_reader` and `attr_writer`, `attr_accessor` is a shorthand for calling the other two)

If you, in your User model write

```
class User
  attr_accessor :some_attribute
```

then you're able to perform

```
u = User.first
u.some_attribute = 'asdf'
u.some_attribute # => 'asdf'
```

but this attribute is not going to be saved to DB, so it may be used as a temporary storage of some value in Rails model.

Another thing to know is that there are only two "values" that are false in Ruby, those are `false` and `nil`.

Using those two tricks you may create a new user and temporarily set this flag on the object

u = User.create
u.just_signed_up = true
u.just_signed_up # => true
u.reload! # fetches record from DB
u.just_signed_up # => nil

and since nil is false, this check will fail for every user except for ones you just created!

Comment: Hey Michael, thanks. As i'm fairly new to Rails i didn't quite understood that. Could you make it more noob-friendly ? :)

Comment: Ok, can you add content of your `User.find_for_facebook_oauth` method to the question? Also check out my extended answer.

Comment: Ok, so in `User.find_for_facebook_oauth` in else clause after `create` add `user.just_signed_up = true` and then you can check it in `omniauth_callbacks_controller`. It will then change to nil after redirect and stay like that.

Comment: So My model should look like this -> https://gist.github.com/Theminijohn/6427268 ?

Comment: Cool :) Thats my Omniauth Callback Controller -> https://gist.github.com/Theminijohn/6428058 . How do i incloude it here ?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/hajder/6428173 lines 11-16. But if I need to write this code for you that means you should reeealy learn the basics first. It will help you a lot in the future if you do!

Comment: I'm a newby in Rails :) Got 1,5 Months now. Actually i tried it the same way you did but i was getting an error so i thought my way was Wrong. With your code i get the same error :( -> http://i.imgur.com/kZZBau5.png

Comment: ah, me idiot! in `find_for_facebook_oauth` in the last line write just `user`

Comment: The reason is - Ruby by default returns the (result of the) last expression, in this case it is assignment, which always returns assigned value. So you need to write user in the end so you get the right return.