# Omniauth Facebook login redirects to signup if user exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

I'm playing around with the `omniauth-facebook` gem to log into a devise session through a facebook account.  When I click the "Sign in with facebook" link, everything goes well: a new account is created, I'm signed in and bounce back to the homepage with a message confirming my new session (very good!).

**Problem:** However when an account already exists, upon clicking the link I am redirected to the `user/sign_up` page.  I've been following [this documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview) from the Devise wiki.  There is a good deal of documentation on similar errors [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23839456/rails-omniauth-facebook-login-redirects-to-sign-up), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24963840/devise-omniauth-facebook-redirecting-to-signup), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31373640/omniauth-facebook-redirects-to-registration-screen-instead-of-creating-user) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18597470/redirect-to-page-after-facebook-sign-up).  Each of the solutions, however, are already implemented in my app (as far as I can tell) OR (in the case of the last link) seem to be based on an older configuration model that seems sufficiently different from the wiki that I'm not sure it's applicable.

**My best guess** is that it has something to do with the callbacks controller, as `@user.persisted?` seems to be coming up false.This leads me to believe that my definition of `@user` is not correct.  See below:

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def facebook
    logger.debug "Inside facebook"
    # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    logger.debug "User is #{@user}"

    if @user.persisted?
      logger.debug "@user.persisted?"
      debugger
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
      logger.debug "user exists"
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end

  def failure
    redirect_to root_path, alert: "Login failed"
  end
end
```

Additionally, my user model is as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
    # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
                 :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]

    def self.from_omniauth(auth)
        where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
            user.provider = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
            user.email = auth.info.email
            user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
            user.fname = auth.info.first_name
            user.lname = auth.info.last_name
        end
    end
end
```

Any suggestions would be certainly welcome!  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have the `after_sign_in_path_for` method anywhere in your project ?

Answer (score 1):

Try Something Like This

```
class Authentication < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user
    # validates :provider, :uid, :presence => true

    def self.from_omniauth(auth)
     authenticate = where(provider: auth[:provider], :uid=>auth[:uid]).first_or_initialize
        if authenticate.user
          authenticate.provider = auth[:provider]
          authenticate.uid =auth[:uid]
        else
            user = User.find_or_initialize_by(:email => email)
            authenticate.provider = auth[:provider]
            user.email = email
            user.first_name = first_name
            user.last_name = last_name
            user.social_image = image
            user.password =  Devise.friendly_token.first(8)
            user.save(validate: false)
            if user.errors.any?
              return user
            else
            authenticate.user_id = user.id
            end
         end
        authenticate.save
        authenticate.user

      end
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
       super resource
  end
```

From what i perceived that you are not going to your landing page

Answer (score 0):

`from_omniauth` never finds an existing facebook user because you are overwriting the provider attribute:

```
where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
```

searches for a user with provider 'facebook' in this case, but none can be found:

```
user.provider = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
```

changes the provider to some random token

just remove that line and it should work properly